# Scala function that takes a multiple parameter anonymous function, as a parameter

Tags: scala

I have a function named sum that can take a single parameter anonymous function as a parameter, and two Integers.

```
def sum (f: Int => Int , a: Int, b: Int): Int =
{
  if(a > b) 0 else f(a) + sum(f, a + 1, b)
}
  sum((x: Int) => x , 2, 10)
```

How could I modify the function definition so that it can take a multiple parameter function, so I could call it like this:

```
sum((y: Int, i: Int) => y + i => x , 2, 10)
```

I know the function I have supplied would be pretty useless when passed a multiple parameter function.. but I am just looking for how it can be done..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
def sum (f: (Int, Int) => Int , a: Int, b: Int): Int = ???
```

Or a curried version:

```
def sum (f: Int => Int => Int , a: Int, b: Int): Int = ???
```

Although you can curry any function just calling `f.curried`